# Why is the cyclomatic complexity of an event 2?

Tags: c#, events, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm scrutinizing cyclomatic complexity in an application with the purpose of testing anything that's got a cyclomatic complexity greater than 1.

What I'm seeing is that a very simple event's add accessor has a cyclomatic complexity of 2. Why is this? Is it because the add method checks first to see if the callback method is already registered?

I created a very simple calculator application to replicate this behavior. I have an event called CalculateComplete that fires when the Calculate() method is complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some class with some event, for example

```
class SomeClass
{
    public event Action<int> SomeEvent;
}
```

Then the IL code generated for the event add method is:

```
SomeClass.add_SomeEvent:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+SomeClass.SomeEvent
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  stloc.1     
IL_0009:  ldloc.1     
IL_000A:  ldarg.1     
IL_000B:  call        System.Delegate.Combine
IL_0010:  castclass   System.Action<System.Int32>
IL_0015:  stloc.2     
IL_0016:  ldarg.0     
IL_0017:  ldflda      UserQuery+SomeClass.SomeEvent
IL_001C:  ldloc.2     
IL_001D:  ldloc.1     
IL_001E:  call        System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Action`1>
IL_0023:  stloc.0     
IL_0024:  ldloc.0     
IL_0025:  ldloc.1     
IL_0026:  bne.un.s    IL_0007
IL_0028:  ret
```

Notice that at the end of the method there is an `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` call, followed by a "branch if not equal". So yes, there is a branch, therefore a cyclomatic complexity of 2.

You may ask why is it like that? The reason is that delegates are immutable. When you add a method to a delegate, you don't modify the original delegate, but you actually create a combined delegate from the existing one and the provided method, and reassign it to the event. See [Delegate.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771(v=vs.110).aspx).

And besides that, the swap between the new and old delegates must be thread-safe, that's why the [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange(v=vs.110).aspx). If the swap failed, try again.

To help, I've translated the IL to C#:

```cs
public void add_SomeEvent(Action<int> arg1)
{
    var local0 = this.SomeEvent;
IL_0007:
    var local1 = local0;
    var local2 = (Action<int>)Delegate.Combine(local1, arg1);
    local0 = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.SomeEvent, local2, local1)
    if (local0 != local1) goto IL_0007;
}
```

Comment: to really translate it into C#, that'd be a `do...while` loop.

Comment: Yes, it would be a `do..while` loop. But labels and `goto`s are valid C# as well, and I wanted to leave it as similar to the IL as possible.